# PySpark: Fastest collect, that keeps the order

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

What is the best way of collecting column values to a list, while maintaining the order.

I usually use the following code to collect the values of a column to a list.

`column_values_list = df.select(column).rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()`

Now I found out that

`pdf = df.select(column).toPandas()`

`column_values_list = pdf[column].tolist()`

seems to be much faster.

Now I am wondering why this is faster and if this is always the case.
Maybe execution speed depends on dataframe size.

Is the pandas solution maintaining the order or can it involve a shuffle?

Comment: I guess that's due to pyarrow speed-ups with pandas

Answer (score 0):

There is a function `collect_list()` from the [Spark SQL API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python//reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.collect_list.html). Since this is a built-in function, the Spark Context can optimize the Execution, so I would use that one.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to keep the order.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of [`sortWithinPartitions`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.sortWithinPartitions) and [`collect_list`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.collect_list)

```py
(df
  .sortWithinPartitions('col1')
  .groupBy('col2')
  .agg(F.collect_list('col3'))
)
```